# Extract tar file after copy without success

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Im copy tar file form folder A to folder B and I want that when 
it finish to copy it to unzip it, I try with the following in my shell script which doesnt work,any idea?

```
cp /home/i557956/A/file.tar  /home/i557956/B
tar -xvf /home/i557956/B/file.tar
```

The copy was success but the tar is not extracted in B folder...

Comment: Have you tried using the pipe operator like `cp /home/i557956/A/file.tar  /home/i557956/B | tar -xvf /home/i557956/B/file.tar` ?

Comment: A pipe doesn't force `tar` to wait for `cp` to complete before it begins; `&&` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move into the B folder before extracting:

```
cp /home/i557956/A/file.tar  /home/i557956/B
(cd /home/i557956/B/ && tar -xvf file.tar)
```

Comment: sorry Im not sure that I understand ,what should I add to the script the cd command?

Comment: `tar` extracts its argument to the current directory, not the directory where the file is. `cd` changes the working directory for the following `tar` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot I mark it as solved , one question since I new to scripting this is working sync and not async I mean in every line of the script?